# delay on menu hover overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to add 0.3 delay on overlay in on:hover menu in .js. I tried FadeIn(), Delay() with dequeue (I might have done something wrong) without luck. Any suggestions how to modify this function?

```
$('.activate-overlay-effect').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.menu-item-responsive', function(e) {
    var target = $('.menu');
    var overlay = $('#overlay');

    if (overlay.length && !$('#' + _.container).hasClass('touch')) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
            target.addClass('hovered');
            overlay.removeClass('hidden');
        } else if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {
            target.removeClass('hovered');
            overlay.addClass('hidden');
        } else {}
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to add/remove the class after a 0.3s delay of both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, or do you actually want to fade the element in/out?

Comment: I was trying any action to check if it applies reading some other cases on StackOverflow, but my desired effect it 0.3 delay on overlay appearing. So to answer your question - the former*

Comment: i will suggest to take a look at `hoverIntent` jQuery plugin. http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html. It does whatever you wanted nicely.

Comment: Try to use SetTimeout with CSS animations: `if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
 setTimeout(function(){
  target.addClass('hovered');
  overlay.removeClass('hidden');
 },300);
}`

Comment: Did not work unfortunetely, the overlay and the hover stopped working

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice plugins that does exactly that. One of them is [$.hoverDelay()](http://ronency.github.io/hoverDelay/). It gives you a configurable delay for both the 'in' and 'out' events like so:

```
$('.activate-overlay-effect').hoverDelay({
    delayIn: 200, 
    delayOut:700,
    handlerIn: function($element){
      $element.css({backgroundColor: 'red'});  
    },
    handlerOut: function($element){
      $element.css({backgroundColor: 'auto'});  
    }
});
```